# Register new user - Problem with SQLSTATE

Tags: php, sql

Implementing a simple register system and after implementing try to test it I get this error message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

My code for register user is:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['lastname'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['lastname']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['pass']))
{
    $name= trim($_POST['name']);
    $lastname = trim($_POST['lastname']);
    $email= trim($_POST['email']);
    $pass= trim($_POST['pass']);
    
    $options = array("cost"=>4);
    $hashPassword = password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$options);
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = :email';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $p = ['email'=>$email];
        $stmt->execute($p);
        
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 0)
        {
            $sql = "insert into members (name, lastname, email, `pass`, created_date,updated) values(:name,:lastname,:email,:pass,:created_date,:updated)";
        
            try{
                $handle = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $params = [
                    ':name'=>$name,
                    ':lastname'=>$lastname,
                    ':email'=>$email,
                    ':pass'=>$hashPassword,
                    ':created_date'=>$date,
                    ':updated'=>$date
                ];
                
                $handle->execute($params);
                
                $success = 'Successfull registration!';
                
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $valName= $name;
            $valLastname= $lastname;
            $valEmail= '';
            $valPass= $pass;

            $errors[] = 'Email address already registered';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = "Email address is not valid";
    }
}
else
{
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name']))
    {
        $errors[] = 'Error 1!';
    }
    else
    {
        $valIme= $_POST['name'];
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['lastname']) || empty($_POST['lastname']))
    {
        $errors[] = 'Error 2!';
    }
    else
    {
        $valLastname= $_POST['lastname'];
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $errors[] = 'Error 4!';
    }
    else
    {
        $valEmail= $_POST['email'];
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['pass']) || empty($_POST['pass']))
    {
        $errors[] = 'Error 5!';
    }
    else
    {
        $valPass= $_POST['pass'];
    }
    
}

}
?>
```

I don't get where the problem could be. I think is that I need to change the date value inserted to the database, and that could be a problem. Can someone test this code and tell me where is the problem?

Comment: You have defined the column `email` twice in your insert: `insert into members (email, lastname, email, ...)`. I'm guessing the first email should be `name`?

Comment: Okay, I fix that I got the same error. Thanks @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I don't know what you did so I don't know why you're still getting that error. Did you change the name of the first email-column in the query or did you remove it? And if you removed it, did you also remove it from the parameters array?

Comment: That parameter was changed to name, now I got the same error. I think the problem is on posting date into database when user was registered. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Please update the question to contain the changes you've made to the code. And a small piece of advice for the future: post the full error message with all the details, such as the line number.

Comment: First you say _"That parameter was changed to name, now I got the same error"_ but when you were asked to update the code in the question to reflect those changes you reply with _"I don't need to change anything because that is my code"_? Which is it? Did you fix the issue I pointed out or not? I yes, that's what you should update in your question. If no, why didn't you change it? Also, the error message you posted is a _partial_ of an error. We're asking you to post the _complete_ error message (incl file and line) and point out in that line it is.

Comment: _Side note:_ There's no need to use both `isset()` and `!empty()` in the same if-expression. Just stick with `!empty()` since that checks if the variable is set as well.

Comment: I will try to use only ```!empty()``` and i will write to you is that work @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I left only ```!empty()``` and got same error ```SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined``` @MagnusEriksson

Comment: The comment about `!empty()` was a side note (not relevant to the issue). We still want to see the _full_ error message and you pointing out what line in your code it happens in, since I don't see how the above code could generate that error anymore. Are you 100% sure it's not complaining on some other query in some other file (or in the same file in some code you haven't posted?)

Comment: I can confirm that the above code works (I just tested it locally). If you still get the same error, it's not from the posted code. Please do more debugging (like checking what file and line the error is thrown in)

Comment: Do you think that problem can be in database when post date format like ```(Y-m-d H:i:s) and that row in database was assigned by 0000-00-00 00:00:00``` @MagnusEriksson

Comment: No. MySQL will just add `00:00:00` as the time. And if the issue were invalid data format, you wouldn't get an error about invalid parameter number. Again, if you still get the same error, this is most likely not where it happens.